# Bug? forge.is.connection.connected() is undefined after forge.reload.applyAndRestartApp even though the device is still connected

Tags: trigger.io

When the app is reloaded with forge.reload.applyAndRestartApp(), forge.is.connection.connected() returns undefined even though the device is still connected to the internet.

Additionally, the forge.event.connectionStateChange event doesn't fire after forge.reload.applyAndRestartApp either. Therefore you can't rely on that event to fire on connection for all cases.

Is this a bug with the Trigger reload system?